# Missing MySQL Database after Windows Upgrade

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, mysql, sql

First of all, please bear with me as I am quite new to HeidiSQL, MySQL, and the concept of relational databases as a whole. I recently started using HeidiSQL in order to create tables for import into QlikView. A couple of weeks ago I upgraded to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8.0. This resulted in a number of errors that hindered my already set agenda for how to import files from Excel into HeidiSQl.

First of all, upon trying to open a new HeidiSQL session I am met by an error message stating the following:

“Error: SQL Error (2003) in statement #0: Can't connect to MySQL server on '(localhost)' (10061)”
Upon checking my MySQL workbench, I could see that my local server was not running, but was “stopped”. Attempting to start the server in the MySQL workbench did not help, however upon Googling the problem I managed to get the server running by finding the mysqld.exe file and running the file “as administrator”.

Getting the server running allowed me to start a session in HeidiSQL with the following details:

- Network type: MySQL (TCP/IP)
- Port: 3306
- Databases: Separated by semicolon

However, the only databases that show up are “information_schema”, “mysql”, and “performance_schema” and not the database that I am looking for, namely “(databasename)”. In the MySQL workbench, the following “schemas” are visible; “information_schema” and “performance_schema”. My question is, how do I go about finding and opening/restoring the aforementioned database?

I was hoping that some of you might have experienced this problem and could shed some light on a solution. If any more information is need regarding my setup, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The tables were able to be created prior to updating to Windows 8.1. It's after having updated to 8.1 that the error message has started appearing, i.e. as if the update interfered with the "connection" between the local database that I had been using and Heidi/MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can still see "databasename" using MySQL Workbench, then use MySQL Workbench to verify that you have granted necessary permissions to the user id for that database.  Then connect to that database with that userid HeidiSQL.